# Why wont my css transition start after I ajax load a new page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I load first page I give my Transition elements a new class "ready" which then starts an CSS transition on first load. I then use ajax to load a new html document for menulinks - but first I remove the "ready" class when a link is clicked to reverse the transition. This works great.

Problem: when the new html document is loaded I make sure that the ready class is added again to start a new transition on the new page. My problem is that the new document only seems to load the element with the ready class and don't recognize the CSS for the element without the ready class, and therefor dont load the animation for the new page. Why is this not working?

Demo: http://svensson.streetstylizm.com/  as you can - on first page the transition starts. Then you click one of the submenus under "photography" you can se it removes the ready class and reverse the transition before it loads the new page, which don't have a working transition.

Code:

```
$(function () {
  $('.v-line, .h-line, .nav, #ban_image img').addClass('ready');
});


$('li#menu-item-318 a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); 
  var linkNode = this;
  $('.v-line, .h-line, #ban_image img')
    .removeClass('ready')
    .one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd   transitionend',   
         function(e) {
    $(".js-pageTransition").load("photo.html .test> *", function() {
      $('.v-line, .h-line, .nav, #ban_image img').addClass('ready');
    }); 
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Indenting code makes it easier. Put the `eventHandler` inside the ready function.

```
$(function () {
  $('.v-line, .h-line, .nav, #ban_image img').addClass('ready');

  $('li#menu-item-318 a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var linkNode = this;
    $('.v-line, .h-line, #ban_image img')
      .removeClass('ready')
      .one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd   transitionend',   
           function(e) {
      $(".js-pageTransition").load("photo.html .test> *", function() {
        $('.v-line, .h-line, .nav, #ban_image img').addClass('ready');
      }); 
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: Yeah sorry for that. Updated my code but having the same problem.